# How can I use a custom font in a new list of elements using tocloft?

Tags: tocloft

I'm trying to create a custom list of equations using `tocloft`, but I'm not really sure how to use a custom font for each entry and its page number.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{extbook}
[...]
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
[...]

\begin{document}

%%%%% To be used in case of custom font %%%%%
\myCustomFont
\fancyhead[EL]{\myCustomFont\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\myCustomFont\nouppercase\rightmark}
% Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries\myCustomFont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\myCustomFont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\myCustomFont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries\myCustomFont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\myCustomFont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\myCustomFont}
% List of Figures
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\myCustomFont}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\myCustomFont}
% List of Tables
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\myCustomFont}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpagefont}{\myCustomFont}
% Lists of Equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newcommand{\listequationsfont}{\myCustomFont}
\newcommand{\listequationspagefont}{\myCustomFont}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}% Width of equation number in List of Equations
%%%%% Lists of equations %%%%%
%%%%% To be used in case of custom font %%%%%

    \frontmatter
    {
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \input{content/titlepage}
        \setcounter{page}{0}
        \cleardoublepage\null\newpage
        
        \input{content/dedica}
        \cleardoublepage
                
        {
          \tableofcontents
          
          \listoffigures
          
          \listoftables
          
          \lstlistoflistings
          
          \listofmyequations
        }
        
        \cleardoublepage\null\newpage
    }
[...]
```

I have already managed to change the font family for the Table of Contents and List of Tables and List of Figures, but I'm not sure how to do the same for my new custom List.
[image: Correct font]

[image: Incorrect font]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I asked the question, I realized how dumb I was.

```
\renewcommand{\cftmyequationsfont}{\myCustomFont}
\renewcommand{\cftmyequationspagefont}{\myCustomFont}
```

Yup.